# How should "Chupacabra: Survive the Night" be tagged?

Tags: discussion, tags

We just got [this question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/18023/elimination-when-a-player-loses-all-herds-but-still-has-a-chupacabra) about the game *Chupacabra: Survive the Night*. The obvious tag for the game ([chupacabra-survive-the-night](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chupacabra-survive-the-night)) is just a bit too long (28 characters). Should we just remove the "the" ([chupacabra-survive-night](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chupacabra-survive-night)), or shorten the whole subtitle ([chupacabra-stn](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chupacabra-stn)), or remove the subtitle entirely ([chupacabra](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chupacabra)) or something else? Do we even have a standard for this?

Comment: On SciFi they use [tag:star-trek-tos] etc to solve this problem. It seems to work well.

Comment: Arqade uses [tag:sonic-black-knight] (which removes connecting words), [tag:ac-revelations] (which abbreviates the main title and not the subtitle), [tag:bad-company-2] (which removes the main title entirely), [tag:plants-vs-zombies-2] (which removes the subtitle), and [tag:swtor] (which abbreviates the entire name), so there isn't really any consistency. That's not to say that your solution is bad, but whether it's better than just removing the subtitle entirely probably depends on whether there are other games with the same title.

Answer (score 6):

Until and unless we discover a specific need to distinguish *Chupacabra: Survive the Night* from some *other* game named "Chupacabra", I'd say we should just drop the subtitle and call it [chupacabra](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chupacabra).  That's the simplest and most obvious solution, and seems to work fine here.

If we *do* find ourselves needing to disambiguate the tag (as has happened with [the star-trek tag on scifi.SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/star-trek/info), for example), something like [chupacabra-stn](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chupacabra-stn) could work.  But if no such need exists, there's little point in making the tag longer than it needs to be.

Answer (score 2):

The question is now tagged with "Chupacabra".